# Arrow and tab keys not working in sbt 1.0.3 console

Tags: sbt

When running **sbt console** with Scala 2.12.4, sbt 1.0.3, MacOS 10.13.1, the arrow keys output codes like ^[[A rather than retrieving the last command and tab outputs a tab character rather than autocompete.  If I directly run the Scala REPL or run **sbt** and then from the sbt command line enter **console**, then these keys operate as expected.  So I can work around this issue, it's just annoying.  I suspect there is some piece of configuration that I'm missing I just haven't been able to find it yet.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue on arch linux. Same scala and sbt versions.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in sbt 1.1.0.  A fix in the [1.1.1 release](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/releases/tag/v1.1.1) resolved the issue.

> Fixes tab completion in console while running in batch mode as sbt console. #3841/#3876 by @eed3si9n

https://github.com/sbt/sbt/releases/tag/v1.1.1