# Arrow and tab keys not working in SBT 1.0.3 console after quitting

Tags: sbt

I'm having a similar issue to: [Arrow and tab keys not working in sbt 1.0.3 console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498370/arrow-and-tab-keys-not-working-in-sbt-1-0-3-console?rq=1) but I only lose arrow/tab functionality after quitting a REPL session with `:q` and then restarting it.

In order to rule out project-specific settings, I've created a dummy SBT project using:

```
» sbt new scala/hello-world.g8
```

If I run `console` I get the expected arrow/tab key behavior:

```
sbt:hello-world> console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
Welcome to Scala 2.12.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_152).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import cats._
import cats._
```

However, if I quit the console session with `:q` and then restart it, I lose the appropriate arrow/tab key behavior (input is up-arrow):

```
scala> :q

[success] Total time: 121 s, completed Jan 25, 2018 8:59:07 PM
sbt:hello-world> console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
Welcome to Scala 2.12.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_152).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> ^[[A
```

Note that arrow keys continue to work in the SBT shell itself, I only lose the correct behavior when re-entering a console session.

I've verified that this only happens with SBT 1.0.3 for me; I get the expected (correct) behavior of arrow and tab keys with SBT 0.13.16. I do not have any global SBT settings, and my `JAVA_OPTS` are: `-Xmx8g -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

Answer (score 4):

After some digging around, it looks like I was experiencing this issue: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3482

Based on discussion there, I verified that running `jline.TerminalFactory.get.init` in my REPL restored normal behavior of the arrow/tab keys.

This has been fixed as of SBT 1.1.0 (perhaps earlier). I've updated to 1.1.0 and everything works fine for me now. Documenting here for posterity.